# 'UINavigationController?' does not have a member named 'navigationBar'

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

I'm currently attempting to change the font of the UINavigationBar title with the following code, but have run into an error when building:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [ NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "DroidSerif", size: 20)]
```

**Error**

```
'UINavigationController?' does not have a member named 'navigationBar'
```

**ViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        self.navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [ NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "DroidSerif", size: 20)]
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

The ViewController is embedded in a Navigation Controller. I apologize, this is my first attempt in Swift. Thinking of sticking with Objective-C.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that your property `navigationController` (you usually do not need the `self` in Swift) is of type `UINavigationController?` (note the `?`). This means it is an optional variable, which can also be nil. You have to use an `!` to unwrap it. Change your line to

```
navigationController!.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [ NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "DroidSerif", size: 20)]
```

See [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/OptionalChaining.html) for more.

Comment: I now get the error `Could not find an overload for 'init' that accepts the supplied arguments`

Comment: Could you give me the definition of the property `navigationController`?

Answer (score 0):

The following works in a .m file extending a `UINavigationController`:

```
//.h
@interface OGONavigationViewController : UINavigationController <UITabBarControllerDelegate>

//.m

#define O_TEXT_DARK_GRAY_COLOR [UIColor colorWithRed:55 / 255.0 green:55 / 255.0 blue:55 / 255.0 alpha:1.0]
#define O_FONT_FAMILY @"Custom Font 2"

[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:
 [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
  O_TEXT_DARK_GRAY_COLOR, NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
  [UIFont fontWithName:O_FONT_FAMILY size:18.0], NSFontAttributeName,nil]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if let navController = self.navigationController {
        navController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [ NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "DroidSerif", size: 20)];
    }
```

Comment: Getting the same error that I did with @returntrue's code `Could not find an overload for 'init' that accepts the supplied arguments`

Comment: Try embed your view controller in a navigation controller in storyboard. I tested it and no error on my machine.